# JavaScript Regex: Match lines and add new line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with a regex expression

I have lines like this:

```
Line1
Line2
/
Line3
Line4
```

I'd like to add a new line after each line EXCEPT the lines starting with /
Goal:

```
Line1
#
Line2
#
/
Line3
#
Line4
#
```

I don't get how to realize this with a single regex call. It always replaces only the first line or 1&3

Comment: [`.replace(/(^[^\/].*)/gm, '$1\\n')`](https://regex101.com/r/c4Caci/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'/(^[^\/].*)/gm'` as a regex

```js
const regex = /(^[^\/].*)/gm;
const str = `Line1
Line2
/
Line3
Line4`;
const subst = `$1\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```